# How to see .net library source code with ReSharper 5 and visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, resharper, symbols

I used to see any .net source code (like System.String) with ReSharper and Visual Studio 2008. since I migrated to Visual studio 2010, this option doesn't give the full source code but just the definitions of the class.

How can I fix this, to use the microsoft's symbols server again?

**Edit**: Maybe the problem is only with .net-4.0 assemblies. is microsoft released symbols to to .net-4.0 assemblies also?

Comment: I don't think that it is problem with .net-4 assemlies. I have tried to see on sources of System.String and it's ok. I use VS2010+R#5.

Comment: Make sure that your project is using .net-4, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft released sources for .NET 4 release, so R# have to work just fine. Some debugging information may be found in View -> Output -> ReSharper after unsuccessful navigation. Sometimes R# can't download sources or symbols files because of server errors on referencesource.microsoft.com side.

Comment: This is where it trying to download for `mscorlib.pdb`: http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/mscorlib.pdb/A21F40D38EAB4B64B449E50DE8F5A3431/mscorlib.pdb

Comment: I found and fixed one bug in .NET 4 symbols support. It'll be available in ReSharper 5.1.1 maintenance release soon.

Comment: thanks. I noticed that I can step into the code when debugging, but not look on the source code when ctrl + click on the class name.

Comment: In addition, when ctrl + click on the class name, I'm getting two windows opened: metadata window, and regular (not source code) window. I think this is maybe because I using also Productivity Power Tools extension.

Answer (score 12):

If you go to `ReSharper -> Options -> Tools -> External Sources`, you can set the preference order of where ReSharper gets its definition view from. Make sure "Sources from symbol files" is checked, and check the options at the bottom of that page.

Answer (score 4):

You can download all of the source and symbols and install it in one go.

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rscc/)

and then follow adrian's advice.

Comment: I suspect the problem is with .net-.4 assemblies.